# Jquery find() only direct children doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a customize navigation ul for my e-commerce. When you click on a category, I want to appear sub-categories and sometimes sub-categories have more sub-categories. But in my code, when I click on a specific category, it's working. But everytime I click on the sub-category (which contain other sub-category) everything is hid. Perhaps this is kinda hard to understand so let me show you my code

HTML

```
<ul class="product-categories">
   <li class="cat-parent">
      <a href="#">Main category</a>
      <ul class="children">
          <li class="cat-parent">
              <a href="#">Sub-category 1</a>
              <ul class="children">
                  <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">blabla1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blabla2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-parent">
      <a href="#">Main category 2</a>
      <ul class="children">
          <li class="cat-parent">
              <a href="#">Sub-category 1-2</a>
              <ul class="children">
                  <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">blabla1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blabla2-2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery('ul.product-categories > li.cat-parent').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var direct_child_ul = jQuery(this).find("> ul.children");
    if(direct_child_ul.hasClass('jq_on')) {
        direct_child_ul.hide().removeClass('jq_on');
    } else {
        direct_child_ul.show().addClass('jq_on');
    }
});
```

my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6cvh0838/2/

As you can see, when you click on "Main category", it's working. If you reclick on it, it will hide, it's working. But if you click on "Main category", then click on "Sub-category 1", it disappears...then just reclick on "Main category" and you will see that the children of "Sub-category 1" it's on display:block;

My issue: How can I click on "Sub-category 1" without hiding the children of "Main category" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Forgot your toggle option...

Here is your solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/pfjsoL9t/2/

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#">Main category</a>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-category 1</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">blabla1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blabla2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Main category 2</a>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-category 1-2</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">blabla1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blabla2-2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('ul li ul').hide();
   jQuery('a').click(function() {
       $(this).parents('li').first().find('ul').first().toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: Instead of clicking on a li, I should have put my click function on a <a>...thank you very much!!! It's working well now :)

Answer (score 0):

i can't put a comment on luc's post, but use .toggle instead of .show and you have your solution.

`$(this).parents('li').first().find('ul').first().toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things going on:

1. You are not preventing propagation - all the cat-parent elements
   in the hierarchy will receive the event. event.preventDefault() does
   not stop propagation. You need to either return false from the event
   handler or call event.stopPropagation();
2. The event handler will be triggered when you click items that are not <li.cat-parent> at
   the enclosing cat-parent, causing the entire parent to close. You
   could determine if the enclosing <li> of the clicked item is
   cat-parent, if not, do not close.

Here's my updates: https://jsfiddle.net/wbdarby/6cvh0838/3/

```
   jQuery('ul.product-categories li.cat-parent').click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var liParent = jQuery(event.target).closest("li");
        if( liParent.hasClass( "cat-parent" )) {
            var direct_child_ul = liParent.find("> ul.children");
            if(direct_child_ul.hasClass('jq_on')) {
                direct_child_ul.hide().removeClass('jq_on');
            } else {
                direct_child_ul.show().addClass('jq_on');
            }
        }
       //return false;
    });
```